# Change download folder destination from command line apps

Tags: 18.04, disk-usage

I got 1 SSD drive split into 50 GB for boot (3,6 GB free space) and 175 GB free on other partition. Also 1 TB disk. Today I noticed that all files are installed in my root directory, where I am running out of space. How can I make space there? Also, is there any way to change my apps destination folder which being downloaded via console? I do not want them to be installed in root.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  3,2M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1   46G   40G  3,3G  93% /
tmpfs           7,9G   52M  7,8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,9G     0  7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2  953M  7,3M  945M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,6G   28K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `df -h | grep -v loop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally suggest creating a LiveUSB of ubuntu and rebooting to it,

then starting gparted and with it resize the partitions one by one.

I think since the partitions are stuck next to each other you'll fisrt have to make the 175GB partition smaller on it's left hand side (this operation might take awhile)

and then you can resize the 50GB partition on the right hand side to take up the free space you created.

alternatively, if you're willing to have a single partition on that drive, and given it contains no mountpoints such as `/home` you can first delete the 170GB partition then resize the 50Gb partition to use the available empty space.

Comment: Can I just format my second partition of this SSD 170 GB, make it unused and later add this space to my boot partition?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am new user to Unix systems and just everything is hard for me at the beginning. I will use this second solution it seems a bit easier :)

Comment: It looks like this http://oi65.tinypic.com/2qints0.jpg I got 250 SSD and one partition has 50 GB which contains root for ubuntu, other is 170 GB which is just empty space at the moment.

Comment: Ok done, I did this with help of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSpGaeHlkoE. I did not know that first should I resize /boot/efi and later my root drive. Thanks for help

Comment: glad to have been of help! if you're satisfied with my answer you can mark this question as resolved my clicking the grey checkmark next to my answer and giving it an up vote :)